# Column heading contained in TSQL variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please see the DDL below:

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable (id int identity, name varchar(30))
INSERT INTO TestTable (Name) VALUES ('Ian')

declare @Test As varchar(100)
set @Test = 'Name'
SELECT @Test FROM TestTable
```

The output from the SELECT is 'Name'.  I want the output to be: 'Ian'.  How?

Comment: How was SQL Server meant to automagically know that what you wanted wasn't just to have `Name` appear once for each row in `TestTable` - there's a logical difference between a *name* and a *string* - and what you had was a string. `SELECT 'Name' FROM TestTable` is different from `SELECT Name FROM TestTable`.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a variable to tell SQL Server what column, table, database etc. you want to use. You need to enclose this type of code in dynamic SQL.

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = N'SELECT ' + QUOTENAME(@Test) + ' FROM dbo.TestTable;';
EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

Here's why [I prefer `sp_executesql` instead of `EXEC()`](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/17/bad-habits-to-kick-using-exec-instead-of-sp_executesql) as a standard best practice, and here's why [you should always use the schema prefix (e.g. `dbo.`) when referencing objects](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix). `QUOTENAME()` can help protect you from [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) in this case, since I don't know where the value for `@Test` ultimately comes from.

Comment: I like this answer so much. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `EXEC` to execute a fabricated SQL string:

```
declare @Test As varchar(100)
set @Test = 'Name'
EXEC ('SELECT ' + @Test + ' FROM TestTable')
```

The standard warning for these answers is be certain that you can control what gets put in the SQL statement or use restrictive rights (e.g. read-only) to execute them, otherwise you could get something like this:

```
declare @Test As varchar(100)
set @Test = '1 ; DROP TABLE TestTable; --'
EXEC ('SELECT ' + @Test + ' FROM TestTable')
```

Comment: You can avoid the injection vulnerability by building the command first and applying `QUOTENAME()` - in which case you'll get an invalid column name error instead of an attempt to drop. You can't do that inline.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a string dynamically and use `exec`

```
EXEC ('SELECT ' + @Test + ' FROM TestTable')
```

Comment: Warning: SQL injection